Could this sum be written as a hypergeometric function
I have the following sum involving the inverse of the central binomial coefficient $\binom{2k}{k}$ and two Pochammer symbols:
$$S(n) = \sum _{k=0} ^{\infty} \frac{(-k)_{bn}^B \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2} - k\right)_{an}^A}{k!^2 \cdot (cn-k-1)!^2}\frac{4^k}{\binom{2k}{k}}$$
where $a,b,c,A, B$ and $n$ are positive integers and $c > \frac34 +\frac{aA+bB}{2}$ to insure convergence. Admittedly, this is a pretty nasty sum, but I only want to find its asymptotic as $n \rightarrow \infty$, so there is hope!
If $S(n)$ would turn out to be a hypergeometric function, the problem would be solved because I would be able to use the following large n asymptotic for the Pochammer symbol
$$\lim _{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{-m}(an+d)_m =a^m$$
Also, notice that $\frac{4^k}{\binom{2k}{k}}$ could be written as$\frac{k!}{\left(\frac12 \right)_k}$ which is very hypergeometric-y.
So my question is: Could $S(n)$ be expressed as a hypergeometric function? And if not, how would I go about finding the large n behavior?

@StevenClark, I'm not sure that's correct. As an example, my version of Mathematica outputs $1$ for $a=b=A=B=n=1$, $c=2$. In fact, I think this series never assumes the value of zero for any choice of parameters
